how to find higher case followed by lower case or just higher case
I am trying to match either a higher-case letter followed by a lower-case letter or just a higher-case letter. Many questions were answered about how to get higher-case or lower-case letters, but I can't find any way to force to group higher-case followed by lower-case if available.
a = 'C57H38BN6Ni(1-,3)'
I want a list ['C','H','B','N','Ni']
I tried -
re.findall('[A-Z]|[[A-Z][a-z]]',a) 
or
re.findall('[A-Z|A-Za-z{2}]',a) 
and also some other combination. and getting ['C', 'H', 'B', 'N', 'N', 'i']
Any suggestion?

Seems like [A-Z][a-z]? would do the job.  Both of your attempts were invalid, because most regex special characters lose their special meaning inside of square brackets.

This is an alternation [A-Z]|[[A-Z][a-z]] where the left side will always match first and the notation for the second alternative [[A-Z][a-z]] is still a single character class. This notation[A-Z|A-Za-z{2}] is a single character class.

You just need to use this expression and It should solve the issue
re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]?|[A-Z]', a)


The alternative is pointless here. Its left side already covers all cases.

Please note on why this works.

@tdelney The [A-Z] is any uppercase letter (A through Z), the [a-z] is any lowercase letter, and the ?means that the most last expression (in our case [a-z] is optional. The unnecessary |[A-Z] expression means that it can also just be [A-Z]. The | character means ‘or’.
